# Generate buttons based on JSON result

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to dynamically create buttons based on JSON result. The number of buttons generated is equal to the JSON information. However, for the name of the button, I get `ReferenceError: locationName is not defined`. Is this the right way to generate the buttons? Also (a bit off topic) how to add a click event that gets the corresponding LocationId?

`<div id="LocationButton"></div>`

```
var locations = [];
function FetchLocations() {
    locations = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Locations/GetLocations",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, x) {
                locations.push({
                    LocationId: x.id,
                    locationName: x.location
                });
            })
            GenerateLocationsButttons(locations);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Retrieving Locations Failed!');
        }
    })
}

function GenerateLocationsButttons(locations) {
    var more = document.getElementById("LocationButton");
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        var t = document.createTextNode(locationName);
        btn.appendChild(t);
        more.appendChild(btn);
    }
}
```

The JSON is generated by ASP.Net MVC 5

```
public JsonResult GetLocations()
    {
        using (ScheduleCalendarContext_V2 cntx = new ScheduleCalendarContext_V2())
        {
            var events = cntx.Locations.Select(x => new {
                id = x.LocationId,
                location = x.LocationName
            }).ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share an example of the JSON structure, rather than the ASP.NET setup?

Comment: `locationName` should be `locations[i].locationName`

Comment: when you create the button you could set its name attribute; btn.setAttribute('name', locationName);

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the location name from the `locations` array element.

And for getting the corresponding location ID, you can add that as a data attribute.

```js
function GenerateLocationsButttons(locations) {
  var more = $("#LocationButton");
  locations.forEach(({locationName, locationId}) => $("<button>", {
      text: locationName,
      data: {
        location: locationId
      }
    }).appendTo(more);
  });
}

$("#locationButton").on("click", button", function() {
  alert("Button ID " + $(this.data("location"));
});
```